# I want to read and show the excel file on UI using Angular

Tags: angularjs, excel, github

The excel file should look like this on UI:

[image]

I tried  github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx and was able to get the excel data in JSON format, but i need to show the data in grid. 
I tried http://brianhann.com/easily-import-spreadsheets-into-ui-grid/ also but I am not getting the grid. I am not sure what is MainCtrl here, i tried using my controller but i shows blank grid.

How can i get the excel data with Table using angular.Is there any library which can read/import excel file.? Or do i need to create table using HTML tags.?
Please suggest a way to achieve this, please help.

Comment: Create a table pattern and `ng-repeat` it. And don't forget to bind an array of your data to this pattern. That's all.

Comment: Use the json from Sheet.js and pass it to a table or grid template of which there are numerous angular modules available

Comment: Should i use HTML table for this purpose.. I mean should i create Table using tr,td tags.? Can you please suggest any grid template which could bbe used

Comment: I tried ui-grid, and was able to see the data on grid which I have passed through controller. But while using js-xlsx I am getting the JSON on UI. But for grid we need to pass the JSON through controller using gridoptions. I need your help for how can I pass the JSON to ui-grid